# Image won't hide on scroll jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Hello**, I am working on a project, I found a free fiddle to use on codepen.io. On the website it works perfectly, when you go to the js fiddle I made for it there is an issue. When you scroll down to the main content the main title and box shows up over the text. Is there a way to eliminate this from happening like showed on the original codepen?

Fiddle [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/gu7dt5oz/)

```js
function EasyPeasyParallax() {
 scrollPos = $(this).scrollTop();
 $('#banner').css({
  'background-position' : '50% ' + (-scrollPos/4)+"px"
 });
 $('#bannertext').css({
  'margin-top': (scrollPos/4)+"px",
  'opacity': 1-(scrollPos/250)
 });
}
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(window).scroll(function() {
  EasyPeasyParallax();
 });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**Weave:** http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor/#dcbf9c586b0e798fce89be31c50e3950

**NOTE:** [zIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) only works for [positioned](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) elements.

All I did is tell `#content` to be `position relative` and it works fine.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #FFF;
  font: 400 1.5em/1.5 "Droid Serif", serif;
  color: #111;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  font: 700 2.8em/1.2 "Droid Sans", sans-serif;
}
h2 {
  font: 700 1.5em/1.5 "Droid Sans", sans-serif;
  margin: 1em 0;
}

#banner {
  background: url(http://f.cl.ly/items/1b2V08451N440W0H420K/bg.jpg) no-repeat fixed 50% 0;
  background-size: cover;
  color: #fff;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: -7px;
  margin-top: -8px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
#bannertext {
  width: 24em;
  position: fixed;
  top: 20%;
  left: 50%;
  border: .5em solid #fff;
  margin-left: -12em;
  padding: 2em 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

#content {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 28em;
  text-align: justify;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 2em;
    z-index: 10;
}
#content p {
  margin: 0 0 2em;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<div id="banner">
  <div id="bannertext">
    <h1>| EX |</h1>
    <p>Get famous on twitter.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="content">
  <h2>EX</h2>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <h2>EX.</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Proin pellentesque, est ut venenatis aliquam, lorem quam porttitor ligula, eget ultrices velit dui sed quam. Praesent vehicula placerat lectus. Nulla pede. Quisque a nulla quis massa pulvinar sagittis. Pellentesque neque massa, mattis vulputate, pellentesque nec, vehicula volutpat, purus. Proin pretium dui et nulla cursus eleifend. Aenean aliquam urna eget urna. Vestibulum euismod elit. Donec eget augue sit amet neque elementum pretium. Proin posuere lacus id lacus. Duis vel justo suscipit neque ornare iaculis.</p>
  <p>Ut urna urna, rhoncus eget, vestibulum tempus, venenatis non, nunc. Nunc consequat quam in nulla. Praesent feugiat posuere orci. Sed ac ante. Mauris pellentesque massa vitae ante mattis bibendum. Quisque dapibus lectus eu eros. Nulla facilisi. Praesent hendrerit egestas erat. Suspendisse at velit. Quisque mollis feugiat est. Curabitur ut leo. Cras auctor semper augue. Pellentesque leo pede, tempus sed, ornare in, venenatis sed, nisl. Quisque est velit, eleifend vitae, mollis ac, adipiscing at, eros. Mauris velit. Etiam nec lorem. Vestibulum pellentesque ligula a velit. Maecenas felis metus, suscipit et, eleifend vel, accumsan vitae, magna. Phasellus ut justo vel magna congue laoreet.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
```

To the #content element.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/gu7dt5oz/1/

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly, z-index only works on positioned elements.

I added "position:relative;" to #content, #content p and #banner and it seems to work.

```
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #FFF;
  font: 400 1.5em/1.5 "Droid Serif", serif;
  color: #111;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
}

h1 {
  font: 700 2.8em/1.2 "Droid Sans", sans-serif;
}

h2 {
  font: 700 1.5em/1.5 "Droid Sans", sans-serif;
  margin: 1em 0;
}

#banner {
  background: url(http://f.cl.ly/items/1b2V08451N440W0H420K/bg.jpg) no-repeat fixed 50% 0;
  background-size: cover;
  color: #fff;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: -7px;
  margin-top: -8px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  position:relative;
}

#bannertext {
  width: 24em;
  position: fixed;
  top: 20%;
  left: 50%;
  border: .5em solid #fff;
  margin-left: -12em;
  padding: 2em 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

#content {
  max-width: 28em;
  text-align: justify;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 2em;
    z-index: 10;
    position:relative;
}

#content p {
  margin: 0 0 2em;
  z-index: 10;
  position:relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the latest version of jQuery and it works fine

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/gu7dt5oz/2/

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"
integrity="sha256-a23g1Nt4dtEYOj7bR+vTu7+T8VP13humZFBJNIYoEJo="
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```